# Set Azure Location Policy Restriction

Tags: arrays, json, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy

I want to define a Azure policy where by deployments can only be made to 'West US' and East US at subscription level.

I understand that I'm trying to populate a array of locations but I'm going wrong some where;

```html
{
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "not": {
        "field": "location",
        "in": "[parameters('allowedLocations')]"
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "allowedLocations": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The list of allowed locations for resources.",
        "displayName": "Allowed locations",
        "strongType": "location",
        "value": [ "West US", "East US" ], 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Azure policy have a concept of Definitions and Assignments. The JSON you provide fits the format of a *definition*.

For the policy to take effect, you'll need to *assign* your definition to the subscription you want policy to apply.

[image]

The policy you are trying to apply is also available as a built-in definition. You can directly assign this definition using Azure portal.

https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/PolicyMenuBlade/Definitions

Answer (score 0):

While creating an [initiative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-policy/azure-policy-introduction#initiative-parameters) or policy definition, it is important that you specify the [definition location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-policy/policy-definition#definition-location).

Refer the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-policy/scripts/allowed-locs) for more information.